# xelatex: set mono font after loading unicode-math and modify \parfillskip leads to big whitespace in texttt

Tags: xetex, fontspec, unicode-math

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmonofont{NewCMMono10-Regular} % any other typewriter font would do

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus 10pt}

\texttt{some text with whitespaces}

\texttt{some-text-with-whitespaces}

\end{document}
```

The result with XeLaTeX would be:

[image]

This does not happen if one writes `\setmonofont` before loading `unicode-math`, or if the line `\usepackage{unicode-math}` is removed.

Since this does not happen with LuaLaTeX, I think it is not the expected behavior? Thus is there some way to fix this?

Comment: `\fontdimen3` stretch component for space should normally be 0pt for monospace fonts but it's  2.625pt. after unicode-math, looking...

Comment: Can you raise at unicode-math github (which is under latex3 these days)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sure, I shall soon write an Issue. I was just asking it here to see if it is something that has been asked before.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it looks more like a fontspec problem. You get the same problem without unicode-math if you reuse the font name in a new (non tt) font family: `\setmonofont{NewCMMono10-Regular} % 
\newfontfamily\blub{NewCMMono10-Regular}`.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear why the interword space gets flexibility. You can repair the misfeature, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmonofont{NewCMMono10-Regular}[
  WordSpace={1,0,0},
]

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus 10pt}

\texttt{some text with whitespaces}

\texttt{some-text-with-whitespaces}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ah I thought there ought to be fontspec key somewhere,  I guess I'll have to upvote this:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Too bad, isn't it?

Comment: disaster.......

Answer (score 3):

The fontdimen parameters 3 and 4 setting the stretch and shrink for a space are being set non zero after `unicode-math` that looks like a bug, you can force them back to 0pt with eg

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}


\setmonofont{NewCMMono10-Regular} % any other typewriter font would do
\AddToHook{cmd/ttfamily/after}{%
  \fontdimen3\font=0pt\relax
  \fontdimen4\font=0pt\relax}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus 10pt}

\texttt{some text with whitespaces\showthe\fontdimen3\font}

\texttt{some-text-with-whitespaces}

\end{document}
```

but that shouldn't be necessary